# What am I thinking?

Tags: riddle

> .. / .- -- / - .... .. -. -.- .. -. --. / --- ..-. / ... --- -- . - .... .. -. --. ..--.. / --- .-. / .- -- / .. / - .... .. -. -.- .. -. --. / --- ..-. / ... --- -- . - .... .. -. --. / - .... .- - .----. ... / -. --- - .... .. -. --. ..--.. / --- .-. / .. ... / .. - / -. --- - .... .. -. --. / - .... .- - / .. ... / .- -.-. - ..- .- .-.. .-.. -.-- / ... --- -- . - .... .. -. --. ..--.. / -- .- -.-- -... . / .. / .- -- / .--- ..- ... - / - .... .. -. -.- .. -. --. / --- ..-. / ... --- -- . - .... .. -. --. / - .... .- - / -- .. --. .... - / -... . / ... --- -- . - .... .. -. --. ..--.. / .. / .- -- / ..- -. ... ..- .-. . / .-- .... .- - / - --- / - .... .. -. -.- --..-- / ... --- / .. / .- -- / - .... .. -. -.- .. -. --. / --- ..-. / -. --- - .... .. -. --. / -.-. --- .-. .-. . -.-. - ..--.. / .-- . .-.. .-.. / .--. . --- .--. .-.. . / ... .- -.-- / - .... .- - / -.-- --- ..- / .- .-. . / .- .-.. .-- .- -.-- ... / - .... .. -. -.- .. -. --. --..-- / -... ..- - / .-- .... .- - / -.. --- / .. / -.. --- / .. ..-. / .. / .- -- / -.. --- .. -. --. / ... --- -- . - .... .. -. --. / .-- .. - .... --- ..- - / - .... .. -. -.- .. -. --. ..--.. / ... --- / .-. . .- .-.. .-.. -.-- / .. / .- -- / .--- ..- ... - / -.. --- .. -. --. / -. --- - .... .. -. --. / .-- .. - .... --- ..- - / .-. . .- .-.. .. --.. .. -. --. / - .... .- - / .. / .- -- / .- -.-. - ..- .- .-.. .-.. -.-- / - .... .. -. -.- .. -. --. ..--..

Now this may seem monotonous, but it makes a riddle more fun.

Comment: Why is encoding with Morse "fun"? It's simply busy-work. Ciphers, especially well-known ones, are *not* automatically fun.

Comment: I'm kind of hoping there's going to be a link to a deeper level, like the message containing steganographic morse code, or the answer being related to ham radio, or something of the sort. We'll see.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is mostly phrased in a language known as:

> Morse code. It can be translated to below. 
>  I AM THINKING OF SOMETHING? OR AM I THINKING OF SOMETHING THAT'S NOTHING? OR IS IT NOTHING THAT IS ACTUALLY SOMETHING? MAYBE I AM JUST THINKING OF SOMETHING THAT MIGHT BE SOMETHING? I AM UNSURE WHAT TO THINK, SO I AM THINKING OF NOTHING CORRECT? WELL PEOPLE SAY THAT YOU ARE ALWAYS THINKING, BUT WHAT DO I DO IF I AM DOING SOMETHING WITHOUT THINKING? SO REALLY I AM JUST DOING NOTHING WITHOUT REALIZING THAT I AM ACTUALLY THINKING?

My possible answer to the question above.

> You are on drugs, and you are hallucinating. You do not know if what you are seeing is real or whether something you are thinking of is actually there. Another possible answer **is** an answer because you may think that it is nothing and it is incorrect, but it might actually be incorrect.

EDIT:

> Is it a dream? You are thinking of things that may never truly be there, but you may also be thinking of things that do exist.

Comment: If it is wrong, could I have some possible hints?

Comment: Actually you are pretty good. I appreciate your answer. Although I had an answer this one would also make sense. But the answer to my question comes simply. How do you think of nothing without realizing that you are thinking of nothing? Explain that to me.

Comment: @PearAmeeP I updated the answer.

Comment: Oh boi I think I'm wrong again :'(

Answer (score 0):

The morse code is:

> I AM THINKING OF SOMETHING? OR AM I THINKING OF SOMETHING THAT'S NOTHING? OR IS IT NOTHING THAT IS ACTUALLY SOMETHING? MAYBE I AM JUST THINKING OF SOMETHING THAT MIGHT BE SOMETHING? I AM UNSURE WHAT TO THINK, SO I AM THINKING OF NOTHING CORRECT? WELL PEOPLE SAY THAT YOU ARE ALWAYS THINKING, BUT WHAT DO I DO IF I AM DOING SOMETHING WITHOUT THINKING? SO REALLY I AM JUST DOING NOTHING WITHOUT REALIZING THAT I AM ACTUALLY THINKING?

The answer *might* be:

> ...Along the lines of "You know nothing, Jon Snow!" (i.e) We think of *nothing* when we don't have any information behind it. Say you ask me to tell about a planet named say **Gxyfghifd**, without any information to back it up, I would be thinking blanks... 
>  **TLDR:** You are thinking of nothing since you don't have any data to back it up with...

Answer (score -1):

Based on the decryption already performed by Azync
Identifying that the provided:

> Morse code encrypted text of:  I AM THINKING OF SOMETHING? OR AM I THINKING OF SOMETHING THAT'S NOTHING? OR IS IT NOTHING THAT IS ACTUALLY SOMETHING? MAYBE I AM JUST THINKING OF SOMETHING THAT MIGHT BE SOMETHING? I AM UNSURE WHAT TO THINK, SO I AM THINKING OF NOTHING CORRECT? WELL PEOPLE SAY THAT YOU ARE ALWAYS THINKING, BUT WHAT DO I DO IF I AM DOING SOMETHING WITHOUT THINKING? SO REALLY I AM JUST DOING NOTHING WITHOUT REALIZING THAT I AM ACTUALLY THINKING?

Led me to consider the source of such:

> introspective questioning which led me to consider the title of this puzzle

and that the individual is thinking:

> Do I exist? Which is a popular reference from the writing of Rene Descartes who questioned the existence of all things inside and outside, if what was being seen was truly present and if thought was something that came to an individual or occurred. Was the object or thing that is seen really there or is it of ones own mind, is one present in a physical reality or is the reality itself a figment of the mind/imagination.  The central result towards the end of his writing is that 'I think therefore I am', do I have an effect on the things around me or are there things around me to which to have an effect, do I exist or not? (spoiler) concluding that because I think I therefore exist and am and that the things around me are real and of my life. (as I recall from reading the text some 20+ years ago.)

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is the answer? Answers without explanation may be deleted.

Comment: Updated my response.  Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I was asking for detail on *why* you think this is the answer *based on the puzzle itself*. Right now, the link between this answer and the actual puzzle seems to just be a vague "made me think of", so I'm not sure how you could have gotten this from the puzzle itself.

Comment: While several edits needed to maintain obscurity, does the newest edit provide the information associated that is/was sought?

Comment: I *see* the decoded text. I fail to see how it is at all related to your answer, other than "circular questioning" -- and I don't see how that single connection makes you think that your "related reference" is the solution. *That*'s what I'm asking - why do you think that this is *the solution*? I see how it's vaguely related, but not how you have enough evidence to think that this is the intended answer.

Comment: So on retrospect, I _did_ have an incorrect response/reference mixing two different "sources"; however, the decoded text to me is a summary of the referenced connection.